# Google Play Download Error?

Tags: google-play-store, downloading

Whenever I try to install any app from the google play, the download doesn't begin. The "Downloading..." word dosn't appear and the download bar doesn't even begin ... Need help :S

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache and/or data for the Google Play app?

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to download an app on a device that has date and time not set properly then also this problem can happen. Check the date and time settig.